# How to use pandas.ewm.mean with a halflife and a non-adjusted decay?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a test dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas
index = pandas.date_range('2022-11-01 08:00', '2022-11-01 08:02', freq='T')
data = [1] + [0] * 2
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, index, columns=['val'])
```

This result in the following dataframe:

> ```
>                       val
> 2022-11-01 08:00:00   1
> 2022-11-01 08:01:00   0
> 2022-11-01 08:02:00   0
> ```

I am now trying to decay the series with a halflife of 1 minute:

```
df.ewm(halflife='1 minute', times=df.index).mean()
```

I get the following result:

> ```
>                       val
> 2022-11-01 08:00:00   1.000000
> 2022-11-01 08:01:00   0.333333
> 2022-11-01 08:02:00   0.142857
> ```

I find this result unexpected, as I would think that with a halflife of 1 minute, the observation at `08:01`, 1 minute later, the value should have decayed by 1/2, yielding 0.5.

Looking at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html), I see there is a parameter `adjust`

When set to false, it calculates the decay as

[image]

This looks like what I want, but when I try to specify `adjust=False` I get the following exception:

```
df.ewm(halflife='1 minute', times=df.index, adjust=False).mean()
```

> NotImplementedError: times is not supported with adjust=False.

and then when I try to remove times, I get a different error:

```
df.ewm(halflife='1 minute', adjust=False).mean()
```

> ValueError: halflife can only be a timedelta convertible argument if times is not None.

So how can I get the decay that I expect, using a halflife?

**Update per comment:**

@RanA pointed out that the following would work:

I'm not sure what the units of halflife are in that function?

I ran the following test:

```
import pandas
index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(['2022-11-01 08:00', '2022-11-01 08:01', '2022-11-01 08:03'])
data = [1] + [0] * 2
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, index, columns=['val'])
df.ewm(halflife=1, adjust=False).mean()
```

Note the index is not regular.

The result is the following:

> ```
>                       val
> 2022-11-01 08:00:00   1.00
> 2022-11-01 08:01:00   0.50
> 2022-11-01 08:03:00   0.25
> ```

Comment: surprisingly , df.ewm(halflife=1,adjust=False).mean() gives you the expected output

Comment: @RanA damn, why did I not try that!? I wonder if it works if the index is not on regular discrete intervals?

Comment: after the test , it seems it assumes it is regular and each row represents that one unit, maybe in case of irregular , we should make it regular then drop the unneeded data unit we find a better solution